# how to enable and disable the button's one & another in oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have create,save,update and delete button's in a form. At  first only create button must be enabled and all other buttons disabled, once we create a record, then the save button is enabled.  The update and delete button is enabled after we click on save button.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable and disable buttons with:

```
set_item_property('BUTTON_NAME',enabled,property_true);
set_item_property('BUTTON_NAME',enabled,property_false);
```

Comment: hi, thank you for reply, how to use in all the buttons which i mentioned in the post

Comment: you should start by checking if a record has been already created when you enter the form --for example, in when-new-form-instance trigger-- and then enable or disable the buttons you need..